# Change the declaring class of a method with Javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

Is it possible to move/copy a method from one class to another with Javassist?

```java
public class A {
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}

public class B {
    // add test() here
}
```

What I've tried:

```java
ctClassB.addMethod(ctClassA.getDeclaredMethod("test"));
```

This results in an exception: `javassist.CannotCompileException: bad declaring class`.

Looking at the Javassist javadocs, I don't believe this is possible, but is there some way to change the declaring class of the method?

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a new CtMethod appears to be working:

```
CtMethod method = ctClassA.getDeclaredMethod("test");
ctClassB.addMethod(new CtMethod(method, ctClassB, null));
```